# Why the function field of an algebraic curve $f(x,y)=0$ can be identified with $\overline{L}(x)[y]/(f)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading the paper [An algorithm for computing the Weierstrass normal form](https://www.math.fsu.edu/~hoeij/compalg/IntBasis/Weierstrass.pdf). I have a question about the function field of an algebraic curve.

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial in $x,y$. Let $L$ be the field generated by the coefficients of $f$. Let $C$ be the curve given by $f(x,y)=0$.

On page 2, Section 2, it is said that the function field $\overline{L}(C)$ can be identified with $\overline{L}(x)[y]/(f)$.

How to prove this fact? Thank you very much.